# New libnss service : getent is empty

Tags: linux, nsswitch.conf

I want to login users base on a local SQLite db. I used this repo [github.com/agamez/libnss-sqlite3](https://github.com/agamez/libnss-sqlite3), placed `libnss_sqlite.so` in lib folder and edited `/etc/nsswitch.conf` as follows, but `getent passwd` is empty.

/etc/nsswitch.conf:

```bash
passwd:         sqlite
group:          sqlite
shadow:         sqlite
...
```

I want to understand working mechanism of PAM and libnss, so please don't suggest other methods.

Comment: That is 12 years old. It very well may work, but still... Your first & last statements sort of contradict each other. If you want an understanding, then use what your distro gave you. If you want something that your users are going to go through, then you should use something else.

Comment: My assumptions is `libnss_sqlite.so` is not even recognized/triggered by underlying mechanism (no error in syslog). I don't find something newer, so I stick to this to test current configs and after that built my own service.

Comment: @Bib Do I need to reboot the system in order to activate `libnss_sqlite.so` for underlying process ?!